# How to Web Scrape the Site further?

Tags: excel, web-scraping

Following is the code which I used to fetch specific variables which are mentioned below.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim s As String, ids(), i As Long
ids = Array(500325, 500510)
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        For i = LBound(ids) To UBound(ids)
            .Open "GET", "https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/ComHeader/w?quotetype=EQ&scripcode=" & ids(i) & "&seriesid=", False
            .send
            s = .responseText
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1) = Split(Split(s, """ROE"":""")(1), Chr$(34))(0)
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 2) = Split(Split(s, """PE"":""")(1), Chr$(34))(0)
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 3) = Split(Split(s, """PB"":""")(1), Chr$(34))(0)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

But I cannot further do it especially mentioned in the Results and Shareholding Pattern box as I earlier thought the code will work with all the variable mentioned on that portal. Has it to with the api or something else? As I don't know much about api, so suggest in this regard.

Link for your ready reference:
https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/larsen--toubro-ltd/lt/500510/

https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/reliance-industries-ltd/reliance/500325/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is wrong. Declare the dynamic array then assign to it.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim s As String, ids(), i As Long
    ids = Array(500325, 500510)
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        For i = LBound(ids) To UBound(ids)
            .Open "GET", "https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/ComHeader/w?quotetype=EQ&scripcode=" & ids(i) & "&seriesid=", False
            .send
            s = .responseText
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1) = Split(Split(s, """ROE"":""")(1), Chr$(34))(0)
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 2) = Split(Split(s, """PE"":""")(1), Chr$(34))(0)
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 3) = Split(Split(s, """PB"":""")(1), Chr$(34))(0)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: QHarr ~ I simply further added things which you already placed in your simple code (of few lines). I presumed that whole web page must have some sort of common element to it for web-scraping. As layman you can understand my thought process while I was onto this. Still looked into the Inspect-Elements as to what else I can do about, but no luck, as all looked hazy to me. Dynamic array seems to me far fetched, to be honest, as I am not much into technical on this. Thanks for the guidance anyway!

Comment: Hi, you changed my existing lines i.e. the array. What do you mean by dynamic array is far-fetched? It is where you don't initially explicitly size the array.

Comment: Read about arrays and dynamic arrays here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/VBAArrays.htm

Comment: As technical jargon I don't get it at first hand. Now that you explained I got it.

Comment: No worries. I do take some things for granted which I shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks I will dig deep into this with the link you provided.